# Antivirus that runs only by request

Tags: software-recommendation, anti-virus

I just want a lightweight antivirus for my Mac that doesn't keep running on background but only scanning a file by request. Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [ClamXav](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/clamxav/id430207028?mt=12) (free/donationware)

> Scan only the files you tell it to or your entire hard drive,
>   whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Sophos Antivirus](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/). You can disable On-access Scanning from within the configuration settings.

[image: On-access Scanning]